# Did Lavan Have Tzara'as?

Tags: vayeitzei, tzaraas-negaim, lavan

The Gemara [Arachin (16a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Arakhin.16a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) lists a few reasons why someone might receive tzara'as:

> א"ר שמואל בר נחמני א"ר יוחנן על שבעה דברים נגעים באין על לשון הרע ועל
> שפיכות דמים ועל שבועת שוא ועל גילוי עריות ועל גסות הרוח ועל הגזל ועל
> צרות העין - Rabbi Shmuel bar Naḥmani says that Rabbi Yoḥanan says:
> Tzara'as come and afflict a person for seven sinful matters: For
> malicious speech, for bloodshed, for an oath taken in vain, for
> forbidden sexual relations, for arrogance, for theft, and for
> stinginess.

It seems that Lavan personified in some of these negative traits as the צרות העין and גזל are on full display throughout his interaction with Yaakov Avinu (See [Bereishis 31:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.31.7?ven=The_Rashi_chumash_by_Rabbi_Shraga_Silverstein&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Additionally, the Chofetz Chaim that Yaakov Avinu prayed to be protected from Lavan's lashon hara in [Bereishis 28:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.20?ven=The_Rashi_chumash_by_Rabbi_Shraga_Silverstein&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en). Add in the connection between Lavan and Balaam (whether a gilgul or ancestor who provided twisted spiritual DNA) that the latter featured:

> עַיִן רָעָה, וְרוּחַ גְּבוֹהָה, וְנֶפֶשׁ רְחָבָה, מִתַּלְמִידָיו שֶׁל
> בִּלְעָם הָרָשָׁע - An evil eye, a haughty spirit and a limitless
> appetite he is of the disciples of Balaam, the wicked. ([Avos
> 5:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Seeing that he fit the bill on so many counts, are there any sources that say Lavan received tzara'as? (Was he completely covered in white tza'aras, which led to his name "white"?)

Comment: Generally speaking tzaraat is applied to high level people who commit some small speech transgression, as a "helpful warning". People who speak genuinely nasty words are not given this gift. The key word is "Adam" as in "when an Adam has a blemish". Adam is the Torah's most complimentary term for a human being. It doesn't apply to people like Lavan

Comment: @RabbiKaii Interesting idea about "Adam." At the same time, Tanach does describe others who aren't on such a high level (e.g., Naaman, an Aramean general) who received tzara'as.

Comment: Yes, good point I was just talking about the tzara'as in the desert, but you are talking about when it is used as punishment.

Answer (score 0):

The similarities are indeed compelling.

The שערי אורה discusses Lavan's connection to the concept of tza'aras [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Shaarei_Orah%2C_Tenth_Gate%2C_First_Sefirah.15?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he),
but not necessarily to say that Lavan himself was stricken with tza'aras.

The same author in his שערי צדק mentions these concepts with different wording [here](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/gikatalia/saare_cedek.htm) - *(search for the words לבן or צרעת)*

More food for thought.  Examine the striking similarities in the following pesukim which would seem to link the two parshios:
[image]

On the flip side, one might derive from the common successive periods of a הסגר of sevens (years / days) in both places, that Yaakov himself was a מוסגר that needed to be sent out and freed and that Lavan was a proverbial נגע afflicting Yaakov during the galus of the latter.  Throw into that mix the fact that Yaakov was negotiating the dual threats of Lavan and Eisav - any hints to this with the multiple mentions of "לבן **אדמ**דם" or "לבנה **אדמ**דמת" in Tazria?

Comment: Don't forget Yaakov spending years dealing with sheep with funny colored skins